# Finding resolvent of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A:l^p\to l^p$ be defined as $Ax=(\frac{n}{n+1}x_{n+1})_{n\geq 1}$, for $p=2$ and $p=\infty$. I have to deduce resolvent, or to solve $(A-\lambda I)x=y$, but I got $\frac{n}{n+1}x_{n+1}-\lambda x_n=y_n$ and don't know find x from this equation.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of a resolvent that u use? $(A-\lambda \cdot I)^{-1}$?

Comment: Calculate $A^k$ and then study the convergence of the series $\sum \lambda^{-k}A^k$

Comment: @Levon Minasian Yes, $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$